# i have json object i want to create plist help please

Tags: iphone, ipad

this is My json Object. it contain array and object. I want to create PLIST file in iPhone using prophetically

=================================================================================

```
{
      "component":[
        {
          "id":1006,
          "name":"Image test 2",
          "child":[
            {
              "id":1101,
              "name":"component score mcq"
            },
            {
              "id":1105,
              "name":"component we score"
            },
            {
              "id":1095,
              "name":"a"
            },
            {
              "id":1103,
              "name":"component scq score"
            },
            {
              "id":1134,
              "name":"Hi this is my first blog from lesson"
            },
            {
              "id":1106,
              "name":"abc"
            },
            {
              "id":1102,
              "name":"component fitb score"
            },
            {
              "id":1096,
              "name":"testkrupsvideo"
            },
            {
              "id":1104,
              "name":"component either score"
            },
            {
              "id":1099,
              "name":"krupsblog updated"
            },
            {
              "id":1224,
              "name":"krupsforum updated"
            },
            {
              "id":1127,
              "name":"reading parent topic test"
            },
            {
              "id":1093,
              "name":"abc"
            },
            {
              "id":1128,
              "name":"ankit parent topic"
            },
            {
              "id":1129,
              "name":"test topic for component",
              "child":[
                {
                  "id":1228,
                  "name":"krupsud"
                },
                {
                  "id":1253,
                  "name":"06-12-2012 we updated"
                },
                {
                  "id":1130,
                  "name":"topic reading"
                },
                {
                  "id":1251,
                  "name":"06-12-2012 fitb"
                },
                {
                  "id":1225,
                  "name":"krupsvideo updated"
                },
                {
                  "id":1249,
                  "name":"06-12-2012 mcq"
                },
                {
                  "id":1250,
                  "name":"06-12-2012 scq"
                },
                {
                  "id":1226,
                  "name":"krupsaudio updated"
                },
                {
                  "id":1227,
                  "name":"krupsflash updated"
                },
                {
                  "id":1252,
                  "name":"06-12-2012 eo"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "id":1124,
              "name":"First dlr wiki for positive test",
              "child":[
                {
                  "id":1125,
                  "name":"Component wiki"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "id":1126,
              "name":"bhushan reading dlr"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save it as below..

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:yourJson];

[dict writeToFile:FilePathWithName atomically:YES];
```